# Spring MVC - Cannot mapping controllers correctly

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller, annotations, mapping

I'm new with Spring MVC and I have to create a project from scratch, I decided to use Spring MVC but have some problems to map the controllers in the servlet-dispatcher.xml and to access methods from the view.

The structure of my project is this:

[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2B4V.jpg)

My web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <!-- "Dispatcher" servlet de Spring -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> <!-- 1 = cuando una peticion sea enviada, Spring sera el primero en atenderla -->
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping> <!-- Se mapea que tipo de peticiones va a atender el servlet de Spring -->
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> <!-- Mismo nombre con que se dio de alta -->
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> <!-- Para atender todas las peticiones seria / -->
        </servlet-mapping>

        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>

        <!-- Archivo de Bienvenida -->
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:simple="http://cxf.apache.org/simple" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/simple 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/simple.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <!-- Mapear URL's de cada controller --> 
    <!-- Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
        for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
        define an explicit mapping for it. -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="login.htm">loginController</prop>
                    <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                </props>
        </property>
    </bean>  

    <!-- ViewResolver: Ubicacion de las vistas que Spring regresará al response -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" />

    <!-- El controller para la vista inicial -->    
    <bean name="loginController" p:viewName="login" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController" />

    <!-- El resto de los Controllers -->         
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean id="indexController" class="com.controller.IndexController" />     

    <!-- INTERNACIONALIZACION -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" /> <!-- Ubucacion de los archivos .properties con los labels -->
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" /> <!-- Idioma por Default -->      
    </bean>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="locale" /> <!-- Variable para interceptar el cambio de idioma -->
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

My Controller [LoginController.java]

```
    package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "validar")
    public ModelAndView login(){
        System.out.println("Entro al controller de Login");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("index"); //Go to Index after validating the user        

        return model;
    }
}
```

My Login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="intl"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Creative, Dashboard, Admin, Template, Theme, Bootstrap, Responsive, Retina, Minimal">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->    
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <!-- font icon -->
    <link href="css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <title>Admin Console</title>
</head>
<body class="login-img3-body" onload="callMe()">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="login-form" id="frmLogin" method="POST">        
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <p class="login-img">
                <h3 align="center"><intl:message code="label.appTitle" /></h3>
                <img width="100%" src="img/logo_infoVialDF.png">
            </p>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<intl:message code="label.username" />"  autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="<intl:message code="label.password" />">
            </div>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"><intl:message code="label.rememberMe" />
                <span class="pull-right"> 
                    <select id="lang" onchange="onChange()">
                        <option value="es">Español</option>
                        <option value="en">Ingles</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" id="lang"/>
                </span>                
            </label>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"><intl:message code="label.loginText" /></button>            
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#frmLogin').submit(function(event){            
            $.ajax({                
                url: 'validar',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response){
                    alert("Exito: "+response);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Error: "+response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function onChange() {        
    var e = document.getElementById("lang").value;
    window.location.href = "?locale="+e;
    e = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;         
    }

    function callMe(){
    var locale = "${pageContext.response.locale}";        
    if(locale=="en")
            document.getElementById("lang").value="en";
    else if(locale=="es")
            document.getElementById("lang").value="es";
    }    
</script>
```

I look that when you start the application, the Login.jsp view is loaded (this work) and pressing Login LoginController and then will go to index.jsp that is the view of the Dashboard from the aplication.

My mistake is that I can not access the LoginController and method "enter".
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing the `action` in your `<form class="login-form" id="frmLogin" method="POST">`

It needs to be like:

`<form class="login-form" id="frmLogin" action="validar" method="POST">`